# Interact with MS SQL Server with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, api, routes

Sorry, if it is a super basic question but I'm stuck with this problem for a while and I'm quite new on node.

I'm making an API to sync some orders into a database. Before inserting we need to validate if the costumer already exists and create it if necessary. I'm setting the variable no to 0 in the beginning of the code and then we need to set it to another number if the customer exists.

If I console log inside of the query function I can access the new value but outside it is unavailable.

```
app.post("/order", verifyJWT, (req, res, next) => {
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var request = new sql.Request();
var EncomendJson = req.body;
let no = 0;
var ndos = 10;

//console.log(EncomendJson.documento.contribuinte);

let contribuinte = EncomendJson.documento.contribuinte; 
if (contribuinte == '999999990') {
    //vamos buscar à base de dados buscar o numero de cliente
     no = 1;

}
else {
    request.query("select count(*) as numero from cl (NOLOCK) where ncont = '"+contribuinte+"' and pncont = 'PT'", function (err, row) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

            var clienteExiste  = row.recordset[0]["numero"]; 
            
            if (clienteExiste == 0) {
                // vamos fazer a criação do cliente
            } else {
                // vamos buscar o numero do cliente à base de dados
            
                 request.query("select no as no from cl (NOLOCK) where ncont = '"+contribuinte+"' and pncont = 'PT'")
                 .then( row1 => {
                     no = row1; 
                     

                    
                 })
            }
            console.log(row1);
            
        
   })
}


// Verifica o número de linhas do documento
var numero_linhas_documento = Object.keys(EncomendJson.documento.vendas).length;

res.json('done'); })
```

Am I doing something wrong on the database query?

Thank you!

Comment: You should **definitely** switch to async/await to simplify your code and avoid such pitfals. Also, learn how to create parametrized queries or you are vulnerable to SQL injection (you are at the moment!!).

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thank you for the advice! I will take a look on the await and async. I've seen the parametrized on other website.